# Function that writes out the sum only writes out 0

Tags: c#

Problem: The sum writes out as 0. How do i make it so that the function Summa() writes out the actual sum out of the 10 numbers that user writes in?

This is probably extremely simple but im new to this :P

All of the things in the code weren't separate before but i wanted if i could move the sum part to it's own function

```
using System;

namespace Array
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number;
            int[] vektor = new int[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < vektor.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
                number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                vektor[i] = number;
            }

            Summa();
        }

        static void Summa()
        {
            int sum = 0;
            int[] vektor = new int[10];
            int i = 0;

            sum = sum + vektor[i];
            Console.WriteLine("The amount is " + sum);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `vector` into the `Summa()` method so it can act on it, and you need to use a `for` loop or similar to then iterate over the array to sum the numbers.

Comment: I think that's a basic misconception here. Just because the two `vektor` variables have the same name, they are _not_ the same variable. `vektor` inside `Summa` is a local one, which "knows" nothing about the one in `Main`.

Comment: tip: naming a namespace/type/etc things like `Array` is going to cause problems re conflicts - for example with `System.Array`

Comment: another tip: In this case, I'd prefer using `int.TryParse` over `Convert.ToInt32`.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a new array called vektor in the Summa() function, instead of using the one created in the main() function. Also you've to iterate through the array to find the sum

Change Summa to :

```
static void Summa(int[] vektor)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            
            for(int i=0; i < vektor.Length; i++) 
            {
            sum = sum + vektor[i];
            }
         Console.WriteLine("The amount is " + sum);
        }
```

And change the function call in the main() to:

```
Summa(vektor);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are summing a *different array*; you'd need to pass the array *in*:

```cs
static void Summa(int[] vektor)
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (var val in vektor)
        sum += val;
    // ^^^ or just use: var sum = vektor.Sum();

    Console.WriteLine("The amount is " + sum);
}
/// ...
Summa(vektor);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you're not passing any information to your method "Summa", but you're instead creating a new Array.
So you need to pass the Array from your main method to you "summa" method.

```
namespace Array
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number;
            int[] vektor = new int[3];

            for (int i = 0; i < vektor.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
                number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                vektor[i] = number;
            }

            Summa(vektor);
        }

        static void Summa(int[] vektor)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            foreach (var item in vektor)
            {
                sum += vektor[item];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The amount is " + sum);
        }
    }
```

}

Also, using foreach loops will make your life much easier in the future.

https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_for_loop.asp

When you're unsure what your program is doing and don't know why it isn't working like it should. Try using the debug feature.
If you're using Visual Studio you can access it by pressing F11.

Lycka till med studierna!

Comment: Got an error in the console when using that code: "Unhandled exception...." :/

Comment: Add using System; at the top of the code.

Comment: I think `sum += vektor[item];` should be `sum += item;`